# With nothing but a Unix timestamp, how to find the nearest previous Monday?

Tags: date, language-agnostic, timestamp, utc, unix-timestamp

How can I, given a Unix timestamp, find the timestamp of the Monday at 0:00, closest before it.

```
mondaybefore = findit(some_random_timestamp)
```

I have no access to calendar info, just the Unix timestamp, which is UTC. Monday is assumed to be a Monday according to [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have to use an appropriate date library. The idea of "Monday" is calendar-specific, will be variant due to daylight saving time (assuming you want a particular time in that Monday), and can differ depending on your timezone (strictly speaking, UNIX timestamps should be based on UTC).

I suppose if you wanted a naive implementation, you could subtract the timestamp of interest from a known Monday (at midnight) and integer-divide by 86,400 (= 24 * 60 * 60). If the resultant value is a 0, you've found a Monday. But this would only be valid within the UTC timezone and wouldn't adjust for daylight saving time.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, the solution would look like this:

```
def find_nearest_previous_monday(t):
    r = (t  - (t % WEEK)) - (3 * DAY)
    if (t - r) >= WEEK:
        r += WEEK

    return r
```

and in C, like this:

```
time_t find_nearest_previous_monday(const time_t t)
{
    time_t r;

    r = (t - (t % WEEK)) - (3 * DAY)
    if (t - r) >= WEEK {
        r += WEEK;
    }

    return r;
}
```